# Change published WebService address in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final

Tags: jax-ws, jboss7.x

We are migrating our web services from JBoss 5 to JBoss 7. The web services are now published with the service name in the URL, which breaks all our existing clients.

How can I force the published address back to what it used to be?

JBoss 5 url: http://localhost:8080/app/MyServiceImpl

JBoss 7 url: http://localhost:8080/app/MyService/MyServiceImpl

Service definition is all EJB annotations:

```
@Stateless
@WebContext(contextRoot = "/app")
@WebService(name = "MyServiceImpl", serviceName = "MyService", portName = "MyServicePort", targetNamespace = "http://...", portName="MyServicePortType", wsdlLocation="/META-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl")

public class MyServiceImpl extends implements MyServicePortType {
    //code for webservice operations
}
```

Basically, I want to remove the serviceName from the URL to have backward compatibility. If I remove serviceName from @WebService, I get an error on JBoss startup, so it's not a solution. The error is like: Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I was saying in the question, if I remove serviceName from @WebService, JBoss7 throws an exception on startup. Looking close on the stack trace, I saw that it can't find the @WebClient because it searches for a name constructed by default and looks like this: MyServiceImplService.

My solution was to rename my @WebClient named MyService into MyServiceImplService. This way I was able to remove the attribute serviceName from @WebService annotation, and provide to JBoss7 a @WebClient with the default name that is searching for. For EJB-based JAX-WS Web Services the default endpoint address is:

host/@WebService.serviceName/@WebService.name

Where, the @WebService.serviceName and @WebService.name are annotation attributes of the Web Service.

So, if I did not provide the serviceName attribute, it was not added to the URL, and now it looks like the one in JBoss5:

http://localhost:8080/app/MyServiceImpl